# Android 2.1 :Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created one application in that I need two fragment, So i declared One fragment class and inside that class i created another static fragment class. i altered main.xml as

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="frag.demo.DActivity$TFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="frag.demo.DActivity$DFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

On running this application , I got runtime exception like

```
05-25 14:39:45.224: E/AndroidRuntime(911): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{frag.demo/frag.demo.JFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: frag.demo.JFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8c6f0
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: frag.demo.JFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8c6f0
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
```

05-25 14:39:45.264: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  ... 11 more

And My JFragmentActivity class extends FragmentActivity.
So please provide me where the code goes wrong...

My Activity class

```
public class DActivity extends FragmentActivity {// from android.support.v4.app.*;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Log.i("DA","active");
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
                == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
            // dialog in-line with the list so we don't need this activity.
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
            DFragment details = new DFragment();
            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
        }
    }
    public static class TFragment extends ListFragment {
        boolean mDualPane;
        int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
        String nos[]={"1","2","3","4","5"};
        public TFragment(){

        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i("TF","active");
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.simple_list,nos));
            View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nos);
            mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
                mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
            }
             if (mDualPane) {
                    // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
                    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                    // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                    showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
                }
        }
         @Override
            public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
            }
         @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                showDetails(position);
            }
         void showDetails(int index) {
                mCurCheckPosition = index;

                if (mDualPane) {
                    // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                    // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                    getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

                    // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
                    DFragment details = (DFragment)
                            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nos);
                    if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                        // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                        details = DFragment.newInstance(index);

                        // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                        // with this one inside the frame.
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.nos, details);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.commit();
                    }

                } else {
                    // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
                    // the dialog fragment with selected text.
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(getActivity(), DActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("index", index);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }


    }
    public static class DFragment extends Fragment {
        String names[]={"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"};
        public DFragment() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    public static DFragment newInstance(int index){
        DFragment f= new DFragment();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("DF","active");
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
         ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
         TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
         int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                 4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
         text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
         scroller.addView(text);
         text.setText(names[getShownIndex()]);
         return scroller;
    }

    }
}
```

And My main activity class is

```
public class JFragmentActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("main","active");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second fragment is inside the first one then the class attribute of second fragment should be like:

```
class="frag.demo.TFragment$DFragment"
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Now I have changed second fragment into separate class with static function and that static function is used by first fragment ...

Comment: Can fragement class be a static one , if so which class should hold that fragment class . I have seen that one in this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Are you declaring this fragment class inside Activity class and that to static fragment class? Because, as per the documentation: "A Fragment is closely tied to the Activity it is in, and can not be used apart from one." The Fragment class has to be a public static class. And if you are declaring Fragment class like what I have said, then use above class attribute: class="frag.demo.YourActivity$DFragment"

Comment: Yes, I put my 2 fragment class as static into one activity called DActivity class. And I changed the main.xml as you said  class="frag.demo.DActivity$TFragment"

Comment: No I got errors 05-25 15:56:32.764: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{frag.demo/frag.demo.JFragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(1169): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c066f0

Comment: Ya.. this error occurs when the link to fragment class is incorrect. Please check the class attribute of both fragments in xml file again, whether its correctly pointing to respective Fragment class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11740/discussion-between-sridhar-and-shrikant)

Answer (score 2):

Your title implies that you are attempting to run this code on 2.1, and if that's the case, that's your problem.

The Fragment class was added in API level 11, ie Android 3.0, so unless you have a Honeycomb tablet or an ICS handset or tablet, you aren't going to be able to run it.

Comment: Your right that the fragment class was added in honeycomb, but there is support in previous APIs via the [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) class

Comment: @i2v2nr20i , But we have supported class for Fragment in  2.1 also

Answer (score 0):

You should add your activity to your manifest file. Look into it for an example code.

Answer (score 0):

If your above code is still right, your main activity JFragmentActivity tries to load the Fragments of DActivity via xml, but thats not possible, because those Fragments are tied to DActivity. So DActivity is the only activity, which is able to call them.

So your `/* Intent */` is right. Apply your `FrameLayout` of your `main.xml` file to a new `DActivity` xml file and load it `onCreate`, then call the intent in your `JFragmentActivity`. Put some random `LinearLayout` in your `JFragmentActivity` and run the app.

The class attribute of the fragments should look like this `class="frag.demo.DActivity$DFragment"`

Comment: 05-29 10:42:09.405: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: frag.demo.DActivity   I got this error

Comment: and ofc add DActivity to your manifest ^^ sorry for the delayed answer